# Adding my own properties to any control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to add my own custom property to any control?

I want to do something similar to e.g. x:Name="aname".

So I could write in xaml:

```
<TextBox local:MyCustomProperty="myValue" />
```

Maybe someone can provide a small sample or a link showing how to do this.

In google I only find markup extensions, which doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

Comment: You should be able to add any properties you want in the XAML code-behind. Have you tried that? If so and it didn't work, please elaborate on that.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to write my own TextBox control. The TextBox is just a sample. I want to extend all controls with my custom property. I tried something like "public static bool MyFunc(this FrameworkElement source, DependencyProperty property)", which extends any control, but I can't call it in xaml.

Comment: Still, there's Tag for every `FrameworkElement` you can use to get/set arbitrary value. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class MyCustomProperty
{
    #region Color dependency property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty;

    public static Color GetColor(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Color)obj.GetValue(ColorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColor(DependencyObject obj, Color value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    static MyCustomProperty()
    {
        //register attached dependency property
        var metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Transparent);
        ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Color",
                                                            typeof(Color),
                                                            typeof(MyCustomProperty), metadata);
    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<DockPanel  custom:MyCustomProperty.Color="{StaticResource MyColor}" >
```